# Is there a way to initialize a const static field from another const static field in a different class?

Tags: c++, static, initialization, constants, field

I'm trying to initialize the state of my `static const` field from (a part of) the state of another `const static` field from a different class in a different file.

In a simplified example:

```cpp
// object.h
class Object {
public:
  Object(std::string s) 
    : s(s)
  {}
private:
  std::string s;
};

// a.h
#include "object.h"
class A {
public:
  static const Object o;
};

// a.cpp
#include "a.h"
const Object A::o { "ObjectToCopyFrom" };

// b.h
#include "object.h"
class B {
public:
  static const Object o;
}

// b.cpp
#include "a.h"
const Object B::o { A::o };
```

In my experience, I found that `B::o` could not initialize from `A::o`. It compiles, but the `std::string B::o` is empty. Am I doing something wrong, or is this simply not possible? Or are there better design strategies for `static const` fields relying on each other?

Comment: Please do some research about *static initalization order fiasco*. Initialization order of `static` objects is indeterminate between [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

Comment: _"Or are there better design strategies for static const fields relying on eachother?"_ Sure, remove the dependency completely and define these in a separate namespace / class, both of the classes A & B rely on.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the info, I will. I think I've got some catching up to do on translation units.

Comment: @AdrianMole thanks this is precisely what I was looking for, glad to see this is possible in newer c++!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From C++17 onwards, you can use `inline` member variables - in the class **declarations** - in the respective *header* files. This avoids the need for definitions of those members in individual *source* files, thus avoiding any ambiguities related to the order of evaluation of different translation units.

Also, in the example you've given, you'll need to make the `A::o` a `public` member, in order for the `B` class to use it (class members are `private` by default).

Here's a possible 'header-only' solution to your problem:

```cpp
// object.h
#include <string>
class Object {
public:
    Object(std::string s_arg) // IMHO, using argument names same as members is not a good idea!
        : s(s_arg)
    { }
private:
    std::string s;
};

// a.h
#include "object.h"
class A {
public: // The "o" member MUST be public in order for the initialization in "B" to work!
    static inline const Object o{ "ObjectToCopyFrom" };
};

// b.h
#include "a.h" // Need to include the "a.h" header to get the definition of "class A"
class B {
    static inline const Object o{ A::o };
};
```